# What's wrong with my if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Excuse my n00bishness to coding I decided yesterday I was going to turn over a new leaf and learn java. Been using code academy but can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
var Chocolate_Cake = ("A");
var Vanilla_Ice_Cream = ("B");
if (Chocolate_Cake===Vanilla_Ice_Cream);
{
console.log("I'm Dumb");
} 
else
{
console.log("I just finished my first course!");
}
```

Since Chocolate Cake *== vanilla ice cream it should result in telling me i finished my first course. However I receive a syntax error: unexpected token use. How should I properly format this?

Comment: (Please take time to revise data used.)

Comment: Code academy does not teach Java. What you have been learning is Javascript, which is a different language.

Comment: Your data choices are really foolish and immature, I would suggest changing your data, especially before posting them on the internet.

Comment: Remember that if you want to declare a string you must do: var varName = "ass";

Comment: I would like to add to these wonderful comments by saying that code academy has forums specifically designed to help students work through tutorials.  Congratulations on trying new things.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use semicolon (;) after your if statement. It should be:

```
if (Chocolate_Cake===Vanilla_Ice_Cream)
```